# Running Streams in Pairs

Tags: sockets, stream

After an extensive search on the internet, I was unable to find an answer to my question. The way I see it, there can only be one input and output stream between sockets. This has created a problem for me. I want to have 2 separate streams that are paired:an input stream with a respective output stream. The reason why is I want to have a thread on the server waiting and listening for a message from the client while also having a thread on the server that is taking info in from the client. Every time I try to write something, the output stream puts everything on the same stream and the reader on the client side cannot distinguish where the code is to be read. Is there any way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to have a thread on the server waiting and listening for a message from the client while also having a thread on the server that is taking info in from the client.

This is a distinction without a difference. There is no difference between 'taking info' and 'listening for a message'.

Your question doesn't make sense. A TCP socket provides one byte stream in each direction. If you want two, open two sockets.